# capistrano: execute without ssh when server is localhost

Tags: deployment, capistrano

I am using capistrano with multistage extension to deploy easily on staging and production servers.

I implemented a lot of tasks, doing setup stuff on the servers. For the different stages I have files like deploy/staging.rb or deploy/production.rb with only some hostname and username changes.

When I create a stage "localhost" with this setting:

```
set :server, "localhost"
```

everything is correctly executed on my local computer. But it is executed with ssh. I have colleagues, not running a ssh server on their computer. So the question is:

How do I tell capistrano to do all command executions invoked by `run` or `capture` without ssh? I do not want to implement every task a second time with `run_locally`.

Comment: I'd recommend migrating your cap tasks to rake then adding cap tasks that call the rake tasks. cap = remote (via ssh) where as rake = local. HTH

Comment: @NathanHyde upvote for the rake hint, but that would mean that ruby/rake is running on all remote servers, isn't it? There is no ruby in our websites, so ruby is not installed on most of the servers. Maybe it is time to migrate to fabric.